# Why does the added raster layer have strange edges?

Tags: raster, geoserver, google-maps

I'm using Geoserver in conjunction with the google maps API to add a raster layer onto a map.  It loads fine, however there's some strange problem with opacity at the edge of the layer where you can see a boundary.  Have you any idea how to fix this?

[image: Screen shot]

(The original is at [obstest.heliohost.org/map2.html](http://obstest.heliohost.org/map2.html).)

I'm totally new to gis and to Geoserver so sorry if this is an obvious question!

Thanks.

Comment: I should add that when I load the image into qgis or udig it looks fine.

Comment: It looks like a reprojection artefact.  Is the raster being reprojected by GeoServer on the fly to produce the above image?  If so, that might explain why it looks OK in QGIS where, perhaps, you are looking at it in its native projection.

Comment: I'm not too sure if it's being reprojected or not.  Is there any way to change how it's projected in this case?

Comment: Match the projection of the raster (using Warp tool in QGIS) to whatever the projection is in your map above.

Comment: Thanks @MappaGnosis, that did the trick.  I didn't think the projection would have been the problem because it looked ok apart from that boundary, but that's just part of being a n00b!  If you write up an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to help!  'Official' answer added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reprojection artefact. The raster being reprojected by GeoServer on the fly to produce the above image. This explains why it looks OK in QGIS where you are looking at it in its native projection.

Match the projection of the raster (using Warp tool in QGIS) to whatever the projection is in your map above.